# Node.JS TCP STUN server not receiving connection from RTCPeerConnection

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, webrtc, stun

I've been doing some localized testing on the `webkitRTCPeerConnection` in Chrome 43, and running a local TCP server in node.js to receive the STUN packets from the peers. My client code (for local testing) is as follows:

```js
// Chrome only

var iceServers = {
    iceServers: [{
      url: "stun:localhost:8080"
    }]
  },
  optional = {
    optional: [{
      DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement: true
    }, {
      RtpDataChannels: true
    }]
  },
  peer1 = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(iceServers, optional),
  peer2 = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(iceServers, optional);

peer1.createOffer(function(offer) {
  peer1.setLocalDescription(offer);
  peer2.setRemoteDescription(offer);
  peer2.createAnswer(function(answer) {
    peer1.setRemoteDescription(answer);
  });
});
```

My Node.JS TCP socket server is only meant to receive the STUN packet and log it for now. It will eventually be a TCP STUN server as outlined in [RFC 5389](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389). For now here's the code for it:

```
var net = require('net'),
    options = {
        allowHalfOpen: true
    },
    port = 8080,
    server = net.createServer(options, connectionListener);

server.listen(port, listening);

function connectionListener(connection) {
    var data = '';

    console.log('Connection opened');

    connection.setEncoding('utf8');

    connection.on('data', function (buffer) {
        console.log('data received');

        data += buffer;
    });

    connection.on('end', function () {
        console.log('data stream ended');

        connection.end();

        console.log('----\n%s\n----', data);
    });
}

function listening() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', port);
}
```

When the client code finishes running, `peer1.iceConnectionState` is `"checking"`, and `peer1.iceGatheringState`, `peer2.iceConnectionState` and `peer2.iceGatheringState` all remain `"new"`. Nothing logs on the TCP server except for `Listening on port 8080`. Can anyone tell me why no connection is opened if `peer1.iceConnectionState` is `"checking"`?